# How to display a 3D model in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, dart-pub

I want to display a 3D model in my application (whose file format is .obj) on my page. The user can rotate this model, like iOS's SceneKit, but I don't have any idea for this. Can anyone help me with how to handle 3D objects in flutter?

Comment: You may want to better explain what you actually want to do or show an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I build 3D (`OpenGL`) apps with Flutter?
>
> Today we don’t support for 3D via OpenGL ES or similar. We have
> long-term plans to expose an optimized 3D API, but right now we’re
> focused on 2D.

https://flutter.io/docs/resources/faq#can-i-build-3d-opengl-apps-with-flutter

Answer (score 1):

you can check out this [repo](https://github.com/hemanthrajv/flutter_3d_obj), but the performance is not really good. I think you can consider using texture to implement.

Comment: Rather than linking to external URL, please add relevant code and explanation in the answer.